# Error <> app.js react

Tags: reactjs, auth

Hola tengo el siguiente problema:

Al tratar de montar mi app en react usando auth0 me aparece el siguiente error en el archivo App.js:

```html
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: D:/Descargas 2/react-auth0-main/src/App.js: Unexpected token (17:11)

  15 |         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
  16 |         {isAuthenticated ? (
> 17 |           <>
     |            ^
  18 |               <Profile />
  19 |               <LogoutButton />
  20 |           </>

 @ ./src/index.js 15:11-27
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Por que simplemente no eliminas el React Frame? No cumple ninguna función ahí. Puedes poner entre paréntesis lo que buscas insertar con el condicional (<Profile /><LogoutButton />)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```
<img src={logo} className="App-logo"  alt="logo" />

<>
    {isAuthenticated ? } // he añadido en esta línea la llave al final
    <Profile />
    <LogoutButton />
</>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).